# Adding new column with data value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, calculated-columns, calculation

forest area to the  I want to **add a column** name (say **ForestAreaPerPopn**) *to find the ratio of forest area to the population(represented by variable Total below)* residing. The data contains the following variables and their values.
[image]

How can I add a column named ForestAreaPerPopn in **Table****ForestAreaPerPop (shown below)**  so that the column contains the data calculated as ratio of forest area to Total.

Comment: `df$ForestAreaPerPopn <- df$ForestArea /  df$Total`.

Comment: Error in df$ForestArea : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable is returned.

Comment: My comment just tells you: it is possible to add a variable `a` to a dataframe `df`, which is the ratio of two variables `b` and `c` by typing `df$a <- df$b / df$c`. Of course, you need to rename the variables according to your needs, e.g. your `b` is probably `Total`. If you expect further help on this very basic question, please provide data by `dput(head(df))`, replace `df` with the name of your dataframe. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

You have a couple of problems. First, your column names have spaces and other special characters. This is allowed but creates all kinds of problems later. I suggest you do something like:

```
colnames(ForestAreaPerPop) <- gsub(' |\\(|\\)', '_', colnames(ForestAreaPerPop))
```

This will replaces any spaces, left or right parens in the colnames with '_'.

Then, something like:

```
ForestAreaPerPop$n <- with(ForestAreaPerPop, Forest_Area_in_ha/Total)
```

should give you what you want.

Some advice: long table names and column names may seem like a good idea, but you will live to regret it. Make them short but meaningful (easier said than done).